# Pandas MultiIndex single level look up is much slower than alternative access patterns

Tags: python, pandas

I have this isolated code snippet that should be self-explanatory:

```
import string
import itertools
import numpy as np
import timeit

index = list(itertools.product(range(100_000), string.ascii_uppercase))

df = pd.DataFrame(index, columns=['i', 'p'])
df['n'] = np.random.randn(len(df))
df_2 = df.set_index('i', drop=False)
df = df.set_index(['i', 'p'], drop=False)

print('One level multiindex loc', timeit.timeit(lambda: df.loc[1000], number=100))
print('Search by column',         timeit.timeit(lambda: df[df.i == 1000], number=100))
print('Non unique index loc',     timeit.timeit(lambda: df_2.loc[1000], number=100))
```

Results:

```
One level multiindex loc 0.8600521469925297
Search by column 0.23243567100143991
Non unique index loc 0.03276521500083618
```

I need to get group of rows by value of `i` (1000 in this example) and I am looking into different access patterns. What I absolutely don't get is why looking up by the first level of a MultiIndex is so slow? I understood the concept of the MultiIndex by it being fast if you are following the hierarchy.

Edit results vary significantly based on pandas version and now more looks like there is something broken with MultiIndex in pandas 1.1.0.

Here are results for 0.25:

```
print('One level multiindex loc 1', timeit.timeit(lambda: df.loc[1000], number=10000))
print('One level multiindex loc 2', timeit.timeit(lambda: df.loc[(1000, ), :], number=10000))
print('Search by column',           timeit.timeit(lambda: df[df.i == 1000], number=10000))
print('Non unique index loc',       timeit.timeit(lambda: df_2.loc[1000], number=10000))

One level multiindex loc 1 3.5869441789999996
One level multiindex loc 2 4.696559950999983
Search by column 26.05316364800001
Non unique index loc 2.409704655000013
```

To compare with 10000 repetitions with `pandas==1.1.0`:

```
One level multiindex loc 1 74.58197712
One level multiindex loc 2 74.65480156499996
Search by column 26.241522830999997
Non unique index loc 0.5789623329999927
```

`pandas==1.0.5`:

```
One level multiindex loc 1 75.16352942799999
One level multiindex loc 2 81.75229192099998
Search by column 25.121312993000004
Non unique index loc 2.481764503999983
```

Answer (score 1):

I need to update my answer, since some additional timings show completely different results:

```
import string
import itertools
import numpy as np
import timeit

index = list(itertools.product(range(100_000), string.ascii_uppercase))

df = pd.DataFrame(index, columns=['i', 'p'])
df['n'] = np.random.randn(len(df))
df_2 = df.set_index('i', drop=False)
df = df.set_index(['i', 'p'], drop=False)
df3 = df.copy().sort_index(level=0)

print('One level multiindex loc with tuple', timeit.timeit(lambda: df.loc[(1000, )], number=100))
print('One level multiindex loc', timeit.timeit(lambda: df.loc[1000], number=100))
print('Explicitly sorted one level multiindex loc', timeit.timeit(lambda: df3.loc[(1000, )], number=100))
print('Explicitly sorted one level multiindex loc with tuple', timeit.timeit(lambda: df3.loc[1000], number=100))
print('Search by column',         timeit.timeit(lambda: df[df.i == 1000], number=100))
print('Non unique index loc',     timeit.timeit(lambda: df_2.loc[1000], number=100))

# One level multiindex loc with tuple 0.05624850000003789
# One level multiindex loc 0.029734599999983402
# Explicitly sorted one level multiindex loc 0.03403290000005654
# Explicitly sorted one level multiindex loc with tuple 0.028620700000146826
# Search by column 0.5066366999999445
# Non unique index loc 0.0468722999999045
```

My pandas `pd.__version__ == 1.0.5`.

It seems like there is some performance regression from version 1.0.5 to 1.1.0.

Sorting the index explicitly seems to increase the the indexing speed, so that MultiIndex `loc` is the fastest method. I don't know what's going on internally, but even the not explicitly sorted `df.index` shows `df.index.get_level_values(0).is_monotonic_increasing` `== True`, so it should be handled like a sorted index. Maybe someone of the pandas core dev team can shed some light?

Comment: hm that code doesn't produce same results for me: `print('One level multiindex loc 1', timeit.timeit(lambda: df.loc[1000], number=100))
print('One level multiindex loc 2', timeit.timeit(lambda: df.loc[(1000, ), :], number=100))`: 0.7810162069945363, 0.689672257998609

Comment: It is 10% faster for me but still slowest by the same order as the original one. Could be related to pandas version?

Comment: pandas version 1.0.5 here. My timings from your code sample are also different. Maybe some performance regression somewhere from 1.0.5 to 1.1.0?

Comment: Please check my edits, results are very different 0.25 vs 1.1.0. Seems like some recent changes caused it.

Comment: yup, seems like it... Thanks for adding the edits. Looking at the pandas changelog, some multiindex behaviour has been reverted to [pandas version < 0.23.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.1.0.html#multiindex-get-indexer-interprets-method-argument-correctly). But seeing that you installed 0.25, this also does not seem to be the cause... So at least I helped finding out what caused the performance regression. ;)

Comment: Do you know what is the best way to reach out to pandas devs about this issue?

Comment: I'd open an Issue on GitHub. In my experience, someone will respond quite fast, providing useful additional details and help. :) Referencing [this blog entry](https://tomaugspurger.github.io/maintaing-performance.html) and also this question may be a good idea. :)